# Cab you use the right division operator in MATLAB to solve a system of linear equations?

Tags: matlab

Just to be clear, this operator: /

Answer (score 0):

`'\'` will solve `A*x=b` : `x=A\b`

`'/'` will solve `x*A=b` : `x=b/A`